# Batch Script search for Interface name by Wireless profile name

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'd like to write a script that will put the name of the wireless interface into a variable and find that interface by the SSID it is connected to. I have:

```
 for /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^|find "Description"') do ( ECHO %%J)
```

This works if there is only 1 wifi adapter, however if mulitple I want it to do something like "where Profile=SSIDNAME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| find "SSID                   : SSID Name"') do (
 for /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| find "Name"') do (
 netsh wlan set profileorder name="SSID Name" interface="%%J" priority=1
 )
 )
```

Basically instead of a "where" clause, it's just a double loop to search first for the SSID, and then for the Named interface